# Are there any Go-ethereum forks supporting segwit?

Tags: go-ethereum

My goal is to create a new token with a different signature algorithm to secp256k1. I would like to use the Go-Ethereum codebase as a starting point.
Segwit is a hard requirement for this idea to work since I need to include 2kb extra data in each signature.
Do any tokens exist similar to Ethereum but with Segwit, ideally by default and somewhat compatible with other codebases in the Ethereum ecosystem?

Comment: Ethereum has a VM that supports a wide variety of programs.